# 'NOT NULL constraint failed' after generating Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running into an error after generating a new scaffold for a table with an existing model: `NOT NULL constraint failed: questions.question_text`.

This has [been covered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710551/sqlite3constraintexception-constraint-failed), but I have not seen an answer for when there is a set null value, as I have done below.

First, I had already generated a model/migration for this table entitled `Questions`, which looks like:

**..._create_questions.rb**

```
 class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :questions do |t|
     t.belongs_to :category, index: true
     t.string :question_text, :null => false

     t.timestamps
     end
   end
 end
```

Notice here that I am specifying the `null => false`. To save some time, I ran a Scaffold command to allow me to enter data into `Questions` easily:

```
 rails generate scaffold Questions --skip
```

After restarting the server, I am running into the error above. Since I am directly addressing the null value, I am unclear of why it triggers an error when I reach the `block in QuestionsController#create` (in other words, when I try to create a Question).

In case it helps, here is my **Question.rb** model as well:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :quiz_questions
   has_many :quizzes, through: :quiz_questions
   has_many :answers
   belongs_to :category
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers

  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure how this particular scaffold works, but the simplest solution would be to specify the default value for this not-null column: `t.string :question_text, null: false, default: ''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using not-null as a form of validation than you would want to add a model validation which enforces this rule as well:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  validates_presence_of :question_text
end
```

This will prevent database driver level exceptions and provide user feedback.

Since you ran the scaffold generator without any attributes I'm guessing that the params whitelist might be empty as well which would cause the above validation to fail since the input is never actually passed to the initializer.

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @question = Question.create(question_params)
    # ...
  end

  private 

    def question_params
      params.require(:question)
            .permit(
              :category_id, 
              :question_text
              answers_attributes: [:foo, :bar, :baz]
            )
    end
end
```